# Kivy canvas doesn't show

Tags: python, canvas, kivy

I am trying to use canvas.
I didn't create .kv files.
It should show up a white line.

```
from kivy.graphics import Line
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


# Canvas from the code
class CanvasExample3App(App):
    class CanvasEx3(Widget):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(**kwargs)
            with self.canvas:
                Line(points=(0, 0, 300, 500), width=2)


CanvasExample3App().run()
```

It shows nothing.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed you code a bit and it works.

You should use build method.
It Initializes the application and always return root widget or widget tree.
Also you can find more information in Kivy documentation [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html?highlight=build#kivy.app.App.build) and [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/basic.html).

```
from kivy.graphics import Line
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


# Canvas from the code
class CanvasExample3App(App):
    def build(self):
        return CanvasEx3()

class CanvasEx3(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            Line(points=(0, 0, 300, 500), width=2)

CanvasExample3App().run()
```